# Delete CSV Rows

Tags: php, csv

How would I go about deleting a specific number of rows from a large csv file?  ie, I am looking to delete the first 100 rows from a file containing over 200,000 rows.  Just curious to see if there is another way to handle things other than completely re-writing the file to a temp file and back to overwrite the original file.

Thanks in advance for any help/suggestions.

Comment: Open the file,  skip the first 100 lines, write the remaining using this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405828/streamwriter-rewrite-the-file-or-append-to-the-file

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be in php?

You can use the unix command `tail` to print every line in a file starting from the nth line:

`tail -n +101 file.csv > trimmed.csv`

Or using PHP:

`$lines = file('file.csv'); // read file as array of lines
$trimmed = array_slice($lines, 100); // slice array at index
file_put_contents('trimmed.csv', implode($trimmed)); // implode and write to file`